# Cassandra policies configuration with CassandraAutoConfiguration

Tags: spring-boot, configuration, cassandra

When using [CassandraAutoConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cassandra/CassandraAutoConfiguration.java) how the yml configuration should look like to configure  `Class<? extends ...>` fields e.g. `reconnectionPolicy: com.datastax.driver.core.policies.ConstantReconnectionPolicy`
with delayMs=3000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems providing a [ClusterBuilderCustomizer](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cassandra/ClusterBuilderCustomizer.java) with custom properties is the only option.

```
  @Bean
public ClusterBuilderCustomizer clusterBuilderCustomizer(CassandraBaseProperties properties) {
    return builder -> builder.withReconnectionPolicy(
            new ConstantReconnectionPolicy(properties.getReconnectionPolicyConstantDelayMs()));
}
```